# v-if per component when loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently, I am loading a few components into a larger grid-component (just a component to group and display child-components).

I am wanting to show/hide a button dependent upon if the object data "featureButtonLink" is = " '' " or not. (if it is not equal, then show the button).

The issue is, I am not sure where the logic to toggle the v-if should be on the child-component, or the "grid" component where the array itself is.

Here is my an example of the code -

**On the Child-component:**

```
<div v-if="link">
<h1>button here</h1>
</div>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'FeatureWork',
    props: [
        'featureTitle', 'featureDescription', 'featureImage', 'featureClass', 'featureButtonLink', 'featureButtonText',
    ],

    data () {
        return {
            link: false
        }
    },

    computed: {
        linkCheck: function() {
            if (this.featured.id.featureButtonLink != '') {
                this.link = true
                return this.link
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

and, here is my "grid" component (the component where I am loading the child component with a v-for + array data, of which has  value inside called "featureButtonLink"):

```
<template>
<div class="feature-work-row card-hover" :class="featureClass">
<div class="work-wrapper">
<!-- <div class="project-tags">
<p class="p-small text-weight-semi">Web Design</p>
<p class="p-small text-weight-semi">Web Design</p>
</div> -->



<div class="columns">
<div class="content">
<h4 class="text-weight-bold">{{ featureTitle }}</h4>
<p class="p-small text-color-regblue">{{ featureDescription }}</p>


<div class="button-container btn-main">
<router-link :to="featureButtonLink"><p class="p-small text-weight-semi">{{ featureButtonText }}</p></router-link>
</div>

<div v-if="link">
<h1>hey there</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="image">
<div class="image-wrapper">
<img :src="featureImage">
</div>

</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'FeatureWork',
props: [
'featureTitle', 'featureDescription', 'featureImage', 'featureClass', 'featureButtonLink', 'featureButtonText',
],

data () {
return {
link: false
}
},

computed: {
linkCheck: function() {
if (this.featured.id.featureButtonLink != '') {
this.link = true
return this.link
}
}
}
}

</script>
```

Or, I guess another question could be...

How do I change the boolean of the child component from the component it is loaded into with the data.

My child component is loaded in a v-if using an array on "parent" component. 
How do I pass the data "true" back into my child component for it to decide whether to show (or not show) a button (whilst using v-if) on that button.

Comment: Why do you have a `link` data item and a `linkCheck` computed rather than just having `link` be the computed?

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `computed` is to cache your data, the way you are using it though, it would require it to be called.

here are some options...

### 1 use `computed`

use computed as intended, by returning the value:

```js
    data () {
        return {}
    },

    computed: {
        link: function() {
            return this.featured.id.featureButtonLink != '';
        }
    }
```

### 2 use a `watch`

```js
    data () {
        return {
            link: false
        }
    },

    watch: {
      featured:{
        immediate: true
        handler: function(val) {
            if (val.id.featureButtonLink != '') {
                this.link = true
                return this.link
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

### 3 use `mounted` lifecycle hook

If the prop does not change is being rendered one-time based on passed prop value, there is little benefit to using a computed. Instead, you could just use the `mounted` lifecycle hook, which would make it run only when it's being mounted. This means it wouldn't react to changes in the value, so I won't show the example.

Comment: and, should this go on the child component, or the component which the component is being rendered via the array?
And, if it should be shown on either, how do I pass the data through to each component? (for example, passing other data to show on the child component is passed using v-bind via props) How would I pass things into data on the child?

Comment: This should be done on the child, to pass the data as a prop to the child use `prop` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html